# How to clear Twitter card cache with api?

Tags: twitter

I am looking for way to clear of twitter card cache using api

I am aware of this tool of Twitter helps in clearing the cache of the cards
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

I am looking for a way to integrate this process into my application. 
What I am looking for is something similiar to what facebook offers (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update)

I did try a simple code like below which happens in the twitter's tool. but I get 403 authorized. Is there a way to to authorize the below request ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.post(
                "https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator/validate",
                {
                    "url" : "http://superbotics.com",
                    "platform" : "Swift-12",
                    "authenticity_token" : "tkWubiFOndkChH58oJmophrLlVoQqbQmY3QZFTayFK6uq"
                },
                function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );

});
```

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the question. The follow up of the same in Twitter community
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-clear-twitter-card-cache-with-api/62974

hope this would answer the question